# How to solve message disorder in RabbitMq?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to know whether or not the messages in RabbitMQ could be disorder due to network jitter or the other things.  If the answer is yes, I'd like to know how to prevent or solve this problem.  If the answer is no, could you please explain why.  It will be really helpful.